# Were there any modifications to udev in order to allow Ubuntu to run on the Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm curious if there was any extreme modifications or patches to udev in order to get Ubuntu running on the Nexus 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no patches to udev, but there are additional rules to modify the android partitions. These can be found in ./etc/udev/rules.d